# Parse a JSON nested array with numbers and strings

Tags: json, vb.net, system.text.json

I receive the following JSON response from a web server:

```
[
  [
    1499040000000,
    "0.01634790",
    "0.80000000",
    "0.01575800",
    "0.01577100",
    "148976.11427815",
    1499644799999,
    "2434.19055334",
    308,
    "1756.87402397",
    "28.46694368",
    "17928899.62484339"
  ]
]
```

How can I parse it to an array using `System.Text.Json`?
I've already tried `String.Split()` and `String.Replace()` (as the brackets and quotes appear in elements) but it's an "ugly" approach.

Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That JSON represents an Array of arrays (well, a single nested array here).
You can parse it as a `List(Of Double())` or `List(Of List(Of Double))`.

The mixed data Type (strings and numbers), can be converted to all numbers, setting a [JsonSerializerOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.-ctor) that specifies the [NumberHandling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonnumberhandling) to use, here set to `AllowReadingFromString`.

```
Dim options = New JsonSerializerOptions() With {
    .NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
}

Dim listOfDouble = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Double()))(json, options)
```

You could also deserialize to a `List(Of Object())` and perform the conversion later or just read the values as strings, calling `.ToString()` when you read an element of the List.

```
 Dim listOfObjects = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of List(Of Object()))(json)
```